# How can I load a page without a refresh animation?

Tags: jquery, css

Best example I can find is [here](http://mrcthms.com/process).

The header of the web page remains static, but when a menu item is clicked the container div below animates and changes. If you refer to the url, it is an entirely new page. The header does not refresh, however the body content does (and animates). I am assuming this is done with jQuery, but the only resources I can find say to use a #, which does work but I would rather go to an actual separate page. I can't find any documentation explaining how this is done, and just looking for a few pointers.

Comment: You think its a real question ?

Comment: You're correct in assuming this was done using jQuery. This isn't the kind of thing Ajax is generally used for, simply because this kind of effect would result in much more code in Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves far too much to the imagination to provide an accurate answer.

You could use Ajax's `XmlHttpRequest`: this would allow you to create a custom page transition effect.

Another alternative would be using jQuery.

• [Here's a tutorial](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/) on making jQuery page transitions

• [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) also supports this

Until you provide more information, there's no way you'll get a much better answer than this one.